# Vue-Router won't work when a route is activated

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Consider about routes below:

1. `/form/1`
2. `/form/2`
3. `/form/3`

When the address is `/` and I click on `/form/1` VueRouter loads my component inside `router-view` but when I'm in `/form/1` by clicking on `/form/2` nothing happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to watch for param changes in the `$route` and perform the correct action (e.g. making an ajax call to retrieve the information for the given id), so:

```
watch: {
  '$route' (to, from) {
   // React to route change
 }
}
```

You may also use the `beforeRouteUpdate` guard (see: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can also add a unique `key` attribute to the `router-view` so that vue forcefully replaces the component instead of reusing it

```
<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
```